# Stop Snaps from accessing user home directory?

Tags: snap, apparmor, firejail

I am trying to sandbox all my applications by default using firejail. Firejail doesn't support snap applications.

It appears that by default if requested by a snap, snapd will grant the snap read/write access to the user's home directory. This means that by default, if there is a vulnerability exploited in a "sandboxed" snap application with network access, it would be trivial for an attacker to grab all the files under $HOME including GPG keys, SSH keys, and of course the user's documents and other files.

Doing some online research lead me to being able to do a `snap disconnect <snap>:<plug interface> <snap>:<slot interface>` which in theory will block access to the home directory. Unfortunately this is an 'all or nothing' approach (no ability to define which folders in home to allow/deny) and must be applied to each snap individually after installation.

Is there a way to apply a "no $HOME access" policy by default to all snaps? If so, is there a way to allow access to some directories in $HOME while denying access to others? My understanding is that apparmor can't be used for this because of the way the snap containers are designed.

Alternate plan: Is there some trickery through which I could re-mount a portion of home (say /home/folderforsnaps) and trick the snaps into thinking that is the home directory?

Comment: Is there an urgent reason why you would want to delve so deep into confinement? I do not think that - at least currently - "global" snap permissions can be set. These are defined by the snap package, i.e., set by the package maintainer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[I]t would be trivial for an attacker to grab all the files under $HOME**

1. Yes, and that's true for every poisoned non-Snap application ever written, too. Do feel free to help test Snaps for nefarious activity (it's a community, after all), and report any poisoned Snaps that you discover.

   A great place to discuss Snap security is the https://snapcraft.io forums. Drop by.
2. snapd/AppArmor does indeed have partial protection for this particular attack: The [home interface](https://snapcraft.io/docs/home-interface) makes the contents of all hidden files (like `~/.ssh` or `~/.thunderbird`) unreadable.

   > home allows access to **non-hidden** files owned by the user in the user’s home ($HOME) directory.

---

**Is there a way to apply a "no $HOME access" policy by default to all snaps?**

No. Each Snap's YAML file defines the access policy that Snap needs in order to function. A global policy would break Snaps that do need access to $HOME, precisely what the developers did not intend.

---

**Is there some trickery through which I could re-mount a portion of home (say /home/folderforsnaps) and trick the snaps into thinking that is the home directory?**

Sure: You could create an LXD container, bind-mount the portion of /home, then install the Snap into the container.

Or you can simply run the Snap as a different user with a limited set of data in their /home.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to view which snap packages use the `home` interface.

```
snap interfaces :home
```

*Note*: `snap interfaces` *is now deprecated. A non-deprecated version of the above command is:*

```
snap connections --all | grep :home
```

Then, you can write a script to `disconnect` each snap package from this interface. Set `SNAPLIST` to the output that you got from above.

```
SNAPLIST=snap1,snap2,snap3
for i in $(echo $SNAPLIST | sed "s/,/ /g")
do
    # call your procedure/other scripts here below
    snap disconnect ${i}:home :home
done
```