# How can I restrict a snap application to /home/user/somedir?

Tags: permissions, snap

I would like to allow a snap application to read and write files to `/home/user/somedir` and restrict the user's ability to read and write files in `home/user/otherdir`. The application cannot be repackaged, so the solution must come from snap itself or some workaround.

It seems [fairly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228899/how-to-access-files-outside-of-home-in-snap-apps) [obvious](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033344/how-to-give-snaps-access-to-somedir) that currently it is [technically unfeasible](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/how-can-i-use-snap-when-i-dont-use-home-user/3352/25) to do this for arbitrary filesystem directories like `/arbitrary/directory/tree` without workarounds not involving snap.

I understand that there are [general workarounds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1314921/stop-snaps-from-accessing-user-home-directory), for example running the snap as a dummy user or in a container and using bind-mount to provide access to only `/home/user/somedir`.

Have I missed a simpler solution in this case?

It seems to me that the technical limitations [noted above](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/how-can-i-use-snap-when-i-dont-use-home-user/3352/25) may not apply, as we need to take away filesystem access provided by `:home` rather than provide them.

Comment: What is the app? What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Firefox and Ubuntu 22.04.